# Issues installing Heroku CLI on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, heroku

I'm unable to install Heroku CLI on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have tried the following -

1. Installing snapd and then "sudo snap install heroku" only to get the error- "error: cannot install "heroku": snap not found".
2. I have even tried "wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh" as some people recommended as alternative.

Both methods have failed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post the output of "sudo snap find heroku"

Comment: sudo snap find heroku  returns -> The search "heroku" returned 0 snaps

Comment: I think I found a way around for now. I'll post it as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I got around the issue following [this discussion thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893627/heroku-error-when-installing)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./"

curl -L https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install heroku
```

I'm not sure why the Heroku installation guide documentation page doesn't specify this.

Answer (score 0):

The site recommends installing using the Standalone version:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#debian-ubuntu

Just follow the commands, and make sure you are running the supported secure protocol.